# Swift set conditional statement when annotation is tapped on mapView for detail view

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a mapView with a couple of custom annotations.
Now what I want is when I tap an annotation the conditional statement voor showLocation: String is set to a specific value.

So for example the annotation.title = Firm of the Future, the showLocation variable is set to "Firm of the Future". And when I tap on annotation with title "Tip 1", the showLocation is set to "Tip 1".

When you tap an annotation a sheet is presented. This works, but I want to show some different information with every annotation.

So I present the MapTipView.

What I tried? A lot of things...
I also found some information but most of it is for Storyboard.

I tried putting the showLocation = "value" inside this function below.
But that only works 1 time. when you click on another annotation you still get the value of the first annotation you clicked.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
                let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "TESTING NOTE")
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        
        
    if annotation.title == "Start" {
                annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoStart")
            let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
            annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
               
}
       showLocation = "Start"
        
    } else if annotation.title == "Firm of the Future" {
            annotationView.image = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")?.withTintColor(UIColor(red: 0.13, green: 0.505, blue: 0.261, alpha: 10), renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
            let size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
            annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
                
            }
          showLocation = "Firm of the Future" 
       }
        else if annotation.title == "Tip 1" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoSchuilplaats")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        showLocation = "Tip 1"
}

// and so for all annotations
```

I tried this and this didn't work also:

```
struct MapTipView: View {
    @Binding var showActionSheet: Bool
    @Binding var showLocation: String
    
    @State var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("Achtergrond")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                
                if annotation.title == "Start" {
                    Text("Start")
                } else {
                    Text("Fout")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the complete code for my mapView:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
  
    let view = UIView()
  let region: MKCoordinateRegion
  let lineCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
    @Binding var manager : CLLocationManager
    @Binding var alert : Bool
    @Binding var currentLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    @State private var UserTrackingMode: MKUserTrackingMode = .follow
    @Binding var showActionSheet: Bool
    @Binding var showLocation: String
    @Binding var showingPlaceDetails: MKPointAnnotation?

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
      let mapView = context.environment.mkMapView
    mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    mapView.region = region
      mapView.showsScale = true
              
      mapView.showsCompass = true
      mapView.showsUserLocation = true
      manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
      manager.delegate = context.coordinator as? CLLocationManagerDelegate
      manager.startUpdatingLocation()

      
      let FOTF = MKPointAnnotation()
      FOTF.title = "Firm of the Future"
      FOTF.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.98837, longitude: 5.81737)
      mapView.addAnnotation(FOTF)
      
      let Start = MKPointAnnotation()
      Start.title = "Start"
      Start.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.98847388992212, longitude: 5.817359983921051)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Start)
      
      let Tip1 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip1.title = "Tip 1"
      Tip1.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de schuilplaats."
      Tip1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.989511, longitude: 5.818118)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip1)
      
      let Tip2 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip2.title = "Tip 2"
      Tip2.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over het wapen."
      Tip2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.993546, longitude: 5.818026)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip2)
      
      let Tip3 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip3.title = "Tip 3"
      Tip3.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de handlanger."
      Tip3.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.994310, longitude: 5.816085)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip3)
      
      let Brief1 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Brief1.title = "Brief 1"
      Brief1.subtitle = "Hier krijg je een brief, los het raadsel op."
      Brief1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.996232, longitude:  5.818456)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Brief1)
      
      let Tip4 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip4.title = "Tip 4"
      Tip4.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de mogelijke dader."
      Tip4.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.997561, longitude: 5.818167)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip4)
      
      let Tip5 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip5.title = "Tip 5"
      Tip5.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over het wapen."
      Tip5.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.998065, longitude: 5.820206)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip5)
      
      let Tip6 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip6.title = "Tip 6"
      Tip6.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de schuilplaats."
      Tip6.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.995915, longitude: 5.828055)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip6)
      
      let Tip7 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip7.title = "Tip 7"
      Tip7.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de handlanger."
      Tip7.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.995339, longitude: 5.831488)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip7)
      
      let Tip8 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip8.title = "Tip 8"
      Tip8.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de schuilplaats."
      Tip8.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.995415, longitude: 5.837951)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip8)
      
      let Tip9 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip9.title = "Tip 9"
      Tip9.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de handlanger."
      Tip9.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.994350, longitude: 5.837638)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip9)
      
      let Tip10 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip10.title = "Tip 10"
      Tip10.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de mogelijke dader."
      Tip10.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.992861, longitude: 5.838441)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip10)
      
      let Brief2 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Brief2.title = "Brief 2"
      Brief2.subtitle = "Hier krijg je een brief, los het raadsel op."
      Brief2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.991260, longitude: 5.837517)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Brief2)
      
      let Tip11 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip11.title = "Tip 11"
      Tip11.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over het wapen."
      Tip11.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.988222, longitude: 5.835309)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip11)
      
      let Tip12 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip12.title = "Tip 12"
      Tip12.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de handlanger."
      Tip12.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.987629, longitude: 5.832252)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip12)
      
      let Tip13 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip13.title = "Tip 13"
      Tip13.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de schuilplaats."
      Tip13.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.982672, longitude: 5.830202)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip13)
      
      let Tip14 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip14.title = "Tip 14"
      Tip14.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de mogelijke dader."
      Tip14.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.983640, longitude:  5.826948)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip14)
      
      let Tip15 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip15.title = "Tip 15"
      Tip15.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over het wapen."
      Tip15.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.982390, longitude:  5.825463)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip15)
      
      let Tip16 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip16.title = "Tip 16"
      Tip16.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de mogelijke dader."
      Tip16.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.978387, longitude:  5.826538)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip16)
      
      let Brief3 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Brief3.title = "Brief 3"
      Brief3.subtitle = "Hier krijg je een brief, los het raadsel op."
      Brief3.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.975684, longitude:  5.826141)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Brief3)
      
      let Tip17 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip17.title = "Tip 17"
      Tip17.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de handlanger."
      Tip17.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.974398, longitude:  5.820770)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip17)
      
      let Tip18 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip18.title = "Tip 18"
      Tip18.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de mogelijke dader."
      Tip18.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.978024, longitude:  5.819883)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip18)
      
      let Tip19 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip19.title = "Tip 19"
      Tip19.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over het wapen."
      Tip19.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.980607, longitude:  5.818235)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip19)
      
      let Tip20 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Tip20.title = "Tip 20"
      Tip20.subtitle = "Hier krijg je meer informatie over de schuilplaats."
      Tip20.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.984846, longitude: 5.818178)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Tip20)
      
      let Brief4 = MKPointAnnotation()
      Brief4.title = "Brief 4"
      Brief4.subtitle = "Hier krijg je een brief, los het raadsel op."
      Brief4.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.987069, longitude: 5.817966)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Brief4)
      
      let Finish = MKPointAnnotation()
      Finish.title = "Finish"
      Finish.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.98831387558797, longitude: 5.817681513726711)
      mapView.addAnnotation(Finish)
      
      

   
    let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: lineCoordinates, count: lineCoordinates.count)
    mapView.addOverlay(polyline)

    return mapView
      
  }

    
  func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {}
    
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
      
      Coordinator(self, showActionSheet: $showActionSheet, showLocation: $showLocation )
  }
    
    
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation, context: Context, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

        let identifier = "Annotation"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        } else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }
       // guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else { return nil }
        
        return annotationView
    }

}

class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @Binding var showActionSheet: Bool
    @Binding var showLocation: String
   
   // @Binding var StartAnnotation: Bool
    
    let uiView = UIView()
    var parent: MapView

    init(_ parent: MapView, showActionSheet: Binding<Bool>, showLocation: Binding<String>) {
    self.parent = parent
      _showActionSheet = showActionSheet
        _showLocation = showLocation
  }

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let routePolyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
      let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: routePolyline)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
      renderer.lineWidth = 7
      return renderer
    }
    return MKOverlayRenderer()
  }
    
    
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
                         didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        //mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
       // mapView.showsUserLocation = true
                print("User location\(userLocation.coordinate)")
            }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        
        if status == .denied{
            
            parent.alert.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
                let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "TESTING NOTE")
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        
        
    if annotation.title == "Start" {
                annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoStart")
            let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
            annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
               
}
        
    } else if annotation.title == "Firm of the Future" {
            annotationView.image = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")?.withTintColor(UIColor(red: 0.13, green: 0.505, blue: 0.261, alpha: 10), renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
            let size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
            annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
                
            }
       }
        else if annotation.title == "Tip 1" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoSchuilplaats")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 2" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoWapen")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 3" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoHandlanger")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Brief 1" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoBrief1")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 4" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoDader")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 5" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoWapen")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 6" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoSchuilplaats")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 7" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoHandlanger")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 8" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoSchuilplaats")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 9" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoHandlanger")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 10" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoDader")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Brief 2" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoBrief2")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 11" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoWapen")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 12" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoHandlanger")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 13" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoSchuilplaats")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 14" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoDader")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 15" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoWapen")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 16" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoDader")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Brief 3" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoBrief3")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 17" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoHandlanger")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 18" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoDader")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 19" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoWapen")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Tip 20" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoSchuilplaats")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
    }
        } else if annotation.title == "Brief 4" {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoBrief4")
                let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
                    _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
                }
                    
    } else if annotation.title == "Finish" {
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "PictoFinish")
    let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
        _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
}
            
        } else {
            
            annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "SilMap")
        let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
        annotationView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
            _ in annotationView.image!.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
        }
            
        
        }
            
                
                return annotationView
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
       // showActionSheet.toggle()
        print("calloutAccessoryControlTapped")
        
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
        
        showActionSheet.toggle()
    
        print("didSelectAnnotationTapped")
    }
}



struct EnvironmentMKMapView: EnvironmentKey {
    typealias Value = MKMapView

    static var defaultValue = MKMapView()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var mkMapView: MKMapView {
        get { self[EnvironmentMKMapView.self] }
        set { self[EnvironmentMKMapView.self] = newValue }
    }
}


struct UserTrackingButton: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewType = MKUserTrackingButton

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKUserTrackingButton {
        MKUserTrackingButton(mapView: context.environment.mkMapView)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKUserTrackingButton, context: Context) { }
}
```

This is the code for my MapViewContent:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapViewContent: View {
 
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
      // FOTF
      center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.98495, longitude: 5.82808),
      span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03)
    )
    
    @State var manager = CLLocationManager()
    @State var alert = false
    @State var currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    
    @State private var UserTrackingMode: MKUserTrackingMode = .none
    @State var showActionSheet: Bool = false
    @State var showLocation: String = ""
    @State var showingPlaceDetails: MKPointAnnotation?
    
  

  @State private var lineCoordinates = [

    // Firm of the Future
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.98847388992212, longitude: 5.817359983921051),
       //and more coordinates for a Polyline
  ];

  var body: some View {
      
      ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        
              MapView(
        region: region,
        lineCoordinates: lineCoordinates, manager: $manager, alert: $alert, currentLocation: $currentLocation, showActionSheet: $showActionSheet, showLocation: $showLocation, showingPlaceDetails: $showingPlaceDetails
    )
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
              
              HStack {
                  
                  Spacer()
                  Text("Locatie volgen:")
                      .font(.headline)
                      //.padding(.horizontal)
                  
                  UserTrackingButton()
                      .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                     // .padding(.horizontal)

                                          
              }.padding()
      }
      .sheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
       MapTipView(showActionSheet: $showActionSheet, showLocation: $showLocation)
      }
      }
      
  }
```

This is the code for my MapTipView (the one that is presented with the sheet):

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapTipView: View {
    @Binding var showActionSheet: Bool
    @Binding var showLocation: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("Achtergrond")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                
                
                if showLocation == "Start" {
                    Text("Start")
                }
                
                if showLocation == "Firm of the Future" {
                    Text("Firm of the Future")
                }
                
                if showLocation == "Tip 1" {
                    Text("Tip 1")
                }

// and so on
                
                else {
                    Text("Fout")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to get a detailed view per annotation?
Thanks is advanced.

EDIT:
This is what I did with the didSelect:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        showActionSheet.toggle()
        
        if annotation.title == "Start" {
            showLocation = "Start"
        }
        if annotation.title == "Firm of the Future" {
            showLocation = "Firm of the Future"
        }
        if annotation.title == "Tip 1" {
            showLocation = "Tip 1"
        }
        //and so on for all annotations
        
    
        print("didSelectAnnotationTapped")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to record the current annotation in your `view(for:)` method.

Instead, set up your view controller (or some other object) to be the map view's delegate and implement the `mapView(_:didSelect:)` from the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol. When that method gets called, record the annotation that was tapped.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, I tried putting the: let annotation = MKPointAnnotation() and then if annotation.title == "Start" {
            showLocation = "Start"
        } in the didSelect function but that doesn't work. Can you tell me how to record the annotation that was tapped?

Comment: Edit your question to show your `mapView(_:didSelect:)` method.